# Flat list interpreted into tree branches in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, tree

I construct a binary tree with MATLAB integer array under the rules:

- 0 or -1 is a terminal;
- list starts from the topmost root; and
- left branch first, then right one.

For example, list `tr`

```
tr = [2 4 0 -1 1 -1 0]
```

represents this tree

```
           2
        /     \
      4         0
    /   \
  -1     1
        / \
      -1   0
```

My implementation involves multiple loops through the list. I am looking for the most efficient way to obtain the four branches of the tree as follows.

```
br1 = [2 4 -1]
br2 = [2 4 1 -1]
br3 = [2 4 1 0]
br4 = [2 0]
```

In addition, I need the "left/right" branch information. Let's say `[2 4 -1]`, I need to know `4` is the left branch of `2`, and `-1` is also the left branch.

P.S. Hopefully, the algorithm works with any tree constructed under the rules.

Comment: Take a look at [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) - one of the most classic algorithms for tree-traversal. It should follow your desired order.  You push each unvisited node onto a stack. When you get to the end of the branch, you pop off that node off the stack. You can implement a very simple stack in MATLAB using arrays. To push onto the stack, simply do `list = [list num];`. To pop off the stack, simply do `list(end) = []`; I would also create a structure where it has 4 elements: `nodeID, root, left & right`. If you want an actual answer, I can write one!

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks a lot! I have learned that and managed to get the depth-first iterator being `1 2 5 6 7 4 3`. How may I proceed from here please?

Comment: Make a structure that has 4 elements as we talked about earlier.  After that, make an array of these structures where each element contains information for that particular node.  As such, when you go through the structure using the array index like you saw above, each element in the structure will contain what is to the left of the node, the right of the node, and the root itself.  You can use that index array you specified earlier to find out all of that information for you.